# Yammer opens App in non resizable Browser Window in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: yammer

In Internet Explorer 11, if somebody clicks on "Try it!" and confirms the OAuth Dialog, Yammer opens the App in the same Browser window as the OAuth Dialog, which is a non resizable 800x480 popup.

However, this is not the case in the other Browsers I've tried (Firefox, IE 10, 9, and 8), which close the OAuth Dialog after confirmation and redirect to the App in the opener window of the OAuth Dialog.

Is there a reason for the behavior of Yammer in Internet Explorer 11 and can I somehow influence how Yammer redirects to my App? With a non resizable 800x480 window it is hardly usable (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejsCn.png).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your embeded code;

'< div id="embedded-feed" style="height:800px;width:580px;">'

with the correct height and width.

Good luck!
Marwin